# Algebra with Probabilities

Tags: probability

If the following inequality holds:
$$5^{-bp_1}p_2\ge5^{-bq_1}q_2,$$
where $b\in(0,1)$ and $p_1$, $p_2$ and $q_1$, $q_2$ are different probability distributions summing to $1$, how can I show that:
$$5^{-p_1}p_2\ge5^{-q_1}q_2?$$
I got up to this point easily and I'm pretty sure this claim is true, so what is the obvious step that I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean that $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $p_1 + p_2 = 1$ and $q_1 + q_2 = 1$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Is the assumption that the first inequality holds for some $b \in (0,1)$ or for all $b \in (0,1)$?

Comment: For all $b \in (0,1)$

Answer (score 0):

If the inequality holds for all $b \in (0,1)$ then this is just a consequence of continuity. You have $f(b) = 5^{-bp_1} p_2 - 5^{-bq_1} q_2$ and $f(b) \ge 0$ for $b  \in (0,1)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(1) \ge 0$ as well.